# MacBook doesn't recognize WD My Book

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mybook

I'm trying to connect a MacBook running Snow Leopard to a Western Digital My Book 512GB external hard drive. The laptop doesn't recognize the drive as being plugged in; it doesn't show up in finder or the device manager. What can I do to get it to recognize the device?

Comment: Have you tested teh drive on a different computer?  Is the drive or cable possibly bad?

Answer (score -2):

Other people find success after half an hour. You may need to reformat it after this.

I mean that the most common solution I hear is that you wait half an hour and then the drive suddenly appears. I've heard this repeated by the technical relatives, or users themselves at least ten times.

Comment: What does this answer mean?

Comment: The drive works on a Windows PC.  Since it isn't even recognized on the MacBook I can't reformat it or anything.